# PHP Foreach String Concatenation

Tags: php

I'm attempting to modify some PHP to suit my needs and I'm having a bit of trouble.

I've created the variable `$mutitag` to hold the names of some variables from which I need to fetch some values.

I made a `foreach` loop to set `$tv` as each value of `$multitag`, fetch the values from the database, and return them into `$get_tags`. However, when I run the code below it only returns the values from the second value of `$multitag` array. How can I correctly concatenate `$get_tags` with all of the returned values? Thanks for your help!

```
$multitag = explode(",", $tv);
if ($tv == '' && !isset($value)) {
    return "No template variable for tags was declared.";
}

foreach ($multitag as $tv) {
    $get_tags = implode(
        $delimiter,
        $modx->getTemplateVarOutput($idname=array($tv), $page_id, $published="1")
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concat the variable get_tags with .=

```
$get_tags = '';
//...
$get_tags .= implode(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$get_tags = '';

foreach($multitag as $tv){
   $get_tags .= implode($delimiter,$modx->getTemplateVarOutput($idname=array($tv), $page_id, $published="1"));
}
```